# PHP/Apache after 32 seconds sleep = no response

Tags: php, apache

PHP 7.4 on Apache

When sleeping for over 31 seconds Apache does not display the last message.
I have added various directives in the script to avoid the problem without success.

Here is the script...

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1); 
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'true');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
ini_set('max_input_time', '300');
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600');
set_time_limit(0);

echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . '<br>';

$delay=32; // enter any number over 31
ob_start();
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 214096)."\r\n<span></span>\r\n";
echo $buffer."Waiting $delay seconds for the last message...<br>";
ob_flush();flush();ob_end_flush();

sleep ($delay);

echo $buffer."The last message!<br>";
exit;
?>
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I just decided to simplify the script and now I get **'500 Internal Sever Error'** at 32 seconds. Here is the simplified script:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1); 
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'true');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
ini_set('max_input_time', '300');
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('mssql.connect_timeout', '300');
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '300');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600');
set_time_limit(0);

echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . '<br>';

$delay=32; // enter any number over 31
echo "Waiting $delay seconds for the last message...<br>";

sleep ($delay);

echo "The last message!<br>";
exit;
?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I just found out that this is a FCGI timeout. Virtualmin says:

> When PHP scripts are run using FCGId mode, this field sets the maximum
> time each script call can run for.

I went to my **Virtual Server>Website Options>Maximum PHP script run time** and changed it and now it works.

However, I cannot find where Virtualmin has applied the change. I am still searching the whole server for something called: FcgidIOTimeout

If anyone knows, I will accept their answer.

Comment: Apache has timeout directives as well...

Comment: Browser and Apache has internal timeouts

Comment: Can you suggest something?